# Selecting node to control animation

Tags: swift, arkit

For my AR-app I am adding a Node from an .dae file. With a tapRecognizer I then try to select the node and add an animation to it.

When the node is selected, I show an UISlider with witch I want to control the animation (scrubbing)

I was able to place the node, select it and scrub through its animation. But since you can not pass parameters to the UISlider, I was acting on a global SCNNode. I can't get it to run with multiple nodes in the session.

My Program fails when I try to add the animationPlayer to the Node, the hitTest returns. It fails because it is nil.

this is for adding a node

```
    func addItem() {
    let dancingNode = SCNNode()
    let results = sceneView?.hitTest(screenCenter, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent).first
    if results == nil{
        print("find surface")
    }else{
        print("place")
        let transform = results!.worldTransform
        let thirdColumn = transform.columns.3
        let sceneURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "art.scnassets/twist_danceFixed", withExtension: "dae")
        let sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(url: sceneURL!, options: nil)
        let animationObject = sceneSource?.entryWithIdentifier("twist_danceFixed-1", withClass: CAAnimation.self)
        animationObject?.speed = 0.0
        let idleScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/idleFixed.dae")!
        for child in idleScene.rootNode.childNodes {
            child.categoryBitMask = BodyType.ObjectModel.rawValue
            dancingNode.addChildNode(child)
            }
        dancingNode.addAnimation(animationObject!, forKey: "dancing" )
        dancingNode.position = SCNVector3(thirdColumn.x,thirdColumn.y,thirdColumn.z)
        dancingNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
        dancingNode.categoryBitMask = BodyType.ObjectModel.rawValue
        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(dancingNode)
    }
}
```

This is the gestureRecognizer:

```
 @objc func tap(recognizer :UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let node = SCNNode()
    let sceneView = recognizer.view as! ARSCNView
    let taplocation = recognizer.location(in: sceneView)
    let hitTest = sceneView.hitTest(taplocation, options: [SCNHitTestOption.categoryBitMask: BodyType.ObjectModel.rawValue])


    for result in hitTest{           
        node.addChildNode(result.node)
    }
    animationPlayer = node.animationPlayer(forKey: "dancing")!

    if !slider.isDescendant(of: self.view) {
        if !hitTest.isEmpty {
            self.view.addSubview(slider)
            }
    }else{
        slider.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

And here is the callback method for the slider:

```
 @objc func changeVlaue(_ sender: UISlider) {
   let moment = sender.value
   animationPlayer.animation.timeOffset = TimeInterval(moment)
   animationPlayer.play()
   animationPlayer.speed = 0.0
}
```

Comment: My problem is, that I really don't know how to reference the Node in the scene.

Comment: Sry guys, it´s hard for me to break it down to a real question. Maybe this wraps it up: is the hitTest node == dancingNode